# I cannot find my ObjectDB odb file

Tags: database, spring, web-applications, object-oriented-database, objectdb

I recently completed this tutorial,

```
http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/spring/run
```

It says the .odb file is created under the Tomcat directory, but I can't find the Tomcat directory. I did a search on my Mac OSX machine and could not find any .odb files. I searched my project and could not find it. I downloaded Tomcat a while ago and searched the folder which eclipse is pointing to. It has to exist somewhere because when I stop the tomcat server in eclipse and restart it the data comes back and persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may specify a full path to your preferred ObjectDB database file path in [step 2](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/spring/entity).

Edit the property `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` in the `persistence.xml` file.

Any path on your machine with appropriate permissions is a valid value.

Comment: <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="$objectdb/db/guests.odb"/>

I cannot figure out where $objectdb is defined. Is that a default to some location?

Comment: That doc page explains that it should be located at the same location as my objectdb.jar or one directory above if objectdb.jar is in a lib or bin folder. I cannot find my objectdb.jar either. I tried file searching and found nothing. Is Maven hiding my objectdb.jar somewhere?

Comment: But if you provide a full path with no $objectdb prefix, e.g. value="c:\my.odb" the value of $objectdb will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in not knowing where the .odb file was, although I was running the tutorial using jetty:run (Ubuntu/Eclipse/Spring). After a bit of hunting I discovered that it was being created in the local maven repo:

```
$ locate *.odb
~/.m2/db/guests.odb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found it in the WEB-INF/db folder of the application itself.